# Android app and login to my database

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

I'm developing an android app similar to a social network. I have created a signup form, a login form and other asynctask that send some data to my database. 
I send data by using POST request that is receipt from php page that execute query to my database e send a JSON result to my application.

For example, when the user log in the App, I send a post to my "login.php" page that check if there is the user in the database. Then, if the user exist in the database, the php page send a JSON to my application that read it and open my home activity.

Now, if I close my app (without logout) or I reboot my phone obviously when I open again my application I have to do login everytime.

How I can maintain the connection open in my app? The user must log off only if he press the logout button.

Also is there any better way to send data such as username and password to my server?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sharedPreferences` for storing your credentials. save the data when you exit the app and when you return to your app get the data from `sharedPreferences` and check to see if login succeeded or not.if the login succeeded start the home page activity or start the login activity. You can use a database to store the credentials, if you want and you can use encryption to send data to and from server

Comment: Ok, now I use this solution, is the best way? Facebook, for example, how do this? I think it doesn't use this method..

Comment: facebook uses their own api. have a look at their api documentation

Comment: +sony, really? Din't know :p